# How to getElementById(function_parameter)

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

How to use `getElementById(function_parameter)`?

```
function myFunction(param1){
      document.getElementById(param1).style.color="#E66C2C";
}
```

Here param1 is a dynamically passed ID and I get the following error in IE11 when I use the above code.
"***Unable to get property 'style' of undefined or null reference***"

It is being called as below:

```js
<a class="someClass1" id="customID1" name="customName1" onClick="javascript:myFunction('customID1');">Custom1</a>

<a class="someClass2" id="customID2" name="customName2" onClick="javascript:myFunction('customID2');">Custom2</a>

<a class="someClass3" id="customID3" name="customName3" onClick="javascript:myFunction('customID3');">Custom3</a>
```

Comment: Did you check if that element is there? There should be an element in your page with attribute `id  == param1` when you call `myFunction(param1)`

Comment: First try logging parameter to ensure that expected value is being passed to function.

Comment: Please provide the corresponding html, then we can say, what is wrong.

Comment: reason could be there is no element found  with  that dynamic id document.getElementById(param1)

Comment: You could always check for the element first, ie `var el = document.getElementById(param1); if (el) el.style.color = "#e66c2c";`

Comment: `onclick="myFunction(this.id)"` would be simpler. Even more simple would be `onclick="myFunction(this)"` and just use `param1.style.color` in your function

Comment: You also have unclosed strings (missing a `"`) on all your `onClick` attributes

Comment: This is not the actual code. As I am not supposed to post it, I missed to close it. So ignore the closing quotes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code worked, it was just full of typos.

1. The first `a` send the wrong parameter to function.
2. All `onclick` as a starting `"` but not an ending one.

Below is a working snippet:

```js
function myFunction(param1) {
  document.getElementById(param1).style.color = "#E66C2C";
}
```

```html
<a class="someClass1" id="customID1" name="customName1" onClick="javascript:myFunction('customID1',this);">Custom</a>

<a class="someClass2 " id="customID2" name="customName2 " onClick="javascript:myFunction( 'customID2');">Custom2</a>

<a class="someClass3" id="customID3" name="customName3" onClick="javascript:myFunction('customID3');">Custom3</a>
```

**A better way**

Just bind by `class` and use `target`:

```js
//The function that handles the click
//This function takes the event and the desired class as arguments
function handleClick(e, c, func) {
  e = e || window.event;
  //Get target
  var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
  //Test for right class
  var hasClass = false;
  for (var i = 0; i < target.className.split(" ").length; i++) {
    if (target.className.split(" ")[i] == c.toString()) {
      hasClass = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (hasClass === true) {
    func(target);
  }
}

//Function to bind click events on class
function bindClassEventClick(cls, func) {
  if (document.body.addEventListener) {
    document.body.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      handleClick(e, cls, func)
    }, false);
  } else {
    document.body.attachEvent('onclick', function(e) {
      handleClick(e, cls, func)
    }); //for IE
  }
}

//Bind event "someClass" click
bindClassEventClick('someClass', function(target) {
  target.style.color = "#E66C2C";
});
bindClassEventClick('someClass2', function(target) {
  target.style.color = "red";
});
```

```html
<a class="someClass">Custom1</a>
<a class="someClass2">Custom2</a>
<a class="someClass">Custom3</a>
```

And then again, at this stage you might as well just implement [jQuery()](https://jquery.com/).

**jQuery**

jQuery is a library build for the specif purpose of easing user interaction with the DOM and generate a uniform cross browser behavior.

```js
jQuery(".someClass").on("click", function() {
  jQuery(this).css("color", "#E66C2C")
});
jQuery(".someClass2").on("click", function() {
  jQuery(this).css("color", "red")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="someClass">Custom1</a>
<a class="someClass2">Custom2</a>
<a class="someClass">Custom3</a>
```